# Processing.js won't run. Minim error?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, processing, processing.js

> Edit: I just want to give a little background. This is a game that is a rogue-like, top down map using a grid of squares "GridSq" as the background over which the sprite moves, controlled by user input via mouse, arrow keys, and WASD keys. Each square of the grid has its own object, as defined below.

I program Processing in a very JAVA influenced style, so I think that may be why script is not running in the browser with Processing.js. I'm using an up-to-date Chrome v 33.0.1750.152 on a OSX 10.9. I'm just getting a white canvas and the following errors.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: GridSq is not defined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

referring to the Processing, respectively:

```
... g[i][j] = new GridSq(cTemp, false, -1, -1); ...

... if (!grid[i][j].shown) { } ...


// Declaration for 'grid' double array
GridSq[][] grid;
```

Here is the class GridSq, which is what the error indicates is not defined. However, it is defined in its class and has been included.

```
class GridSq {

  String type;
  boolean movable;
  int goblin;
  int chest;
  boolean shown;

  GridSq(String t, boolean m, int g, int c) {
    type = t;
    movable = m;
    goblin = g;
    chest = c;
    shown = false;
  }
}
```

In my HTML I am importing Processing.js and minim.js for sound.

```
<script src="js/processing.js"></script>
<script src="js/minim.js"></script>

<article id="baliDiv" title="Bali Brawl">
  <canvas data-processing-sources="pde/BaliBrawl/BaliBrawl.pde"></canvas>
</article>
```

The two problems I ran into refactoring this for Processing.js was A) changing all char types to String types and B) importing minim. I thought I solved both those problems. Obviously the game is running in Processing (after importing minim).

I have tried both leaving out the original minim import and leaving it in. - import ddf.minim.*;

From what I can tell it's happening when the GridSq constructor is called for the first time. I think the error is happening here:

new GridSq("T", false, -1, -1); is calling

```
// GridSq constructor from GridSq Class
// The errors I am receiving indicate that the first time this constructor is called
// is when I am getting an error
GridSq(String t, boolean m, int g, int c) {
    type = t;
    movable = m;
    goblin = g;
    chest = c;
    shown = false;
}
```

It is live right now at http://stephenatpurchase.com/ . The div containing the canvas is loaded, but style=display:none; so you can just open up the JavaScript console and see the errors right away. No need to navigate to it, it's just showing a blank canvas anyway.

There is a chance that the error is happening somewhere else in my Processing code, but it's too much to post it all here. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: your page only loads BaliBrawl.pde, which does not contain any class definition for `GridSq`

Comment: Mike - You were exactly right. While in regular Processing, classes can be accessed automatically as long as they are in the same folder. In processing.js, all classes must be included in the primary class as far as I know. After doing this, and adjusting the 'data' file name calls, it is absolutely working. You really put me on the right track with that comment, thank you so much.

Comment: they don't have to be. You can simply indicate multiple loads using `data-processing-sources="BaliBrawl.pde GridSq.pde etc.pde"`, space delimited. Processing.js will then load all those files